# Compile error on type comparison

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I get the compile error shown below saying that the ErrFieldMismatch type is missing an `Error()` method, but as shown in the last code chunk, it is not.

Any idea to why I cannot perform the type comparison for this?

### Error

`impossible type switch case: err (type error) cannot have dynamic type "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore".ErrFieldMismatch (missing Error method)`

### my code

```
type Program struct {
    aemodel.Base

    Name        string   `json:"name" required:"true"`
    Public      bool     `json:"isPublic"`
    Description string   `json:"description" required:"true"`
    Default     bool     `json:"isDefault"`
    Tags        []string `json:"tags"`

    // Level int
}

// Load - PropertyLoadSaver interface
func (p *Program) Load(ps []datastore.Property) error {
    if err := datastore.LoadStruct(p, ps); err != nil {
        switch err.(type) {
        case datastore.ErrFieldMismatch:  // <-- Failure point
            return nil
        default:
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

### appengine code

```
type ErrFieldMismatch struct {
    StructType reflect.Type
    FieldName  string
    Reason     string
}

func (e *ErrFieldMismatch) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("datastore: cannot load field %q into a %q: %s",
        e.FieldName, e.StructType, e.Reason)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Error` method is defined on the type that is a pointer to `datastore.ErrFieldMismatch`, i.e., `Error` is defined on `*datastore.ErrFieldMismatch`, hence it's only `*datastore.ErrFieldMismatch` that implements the `Error` interface.

Try changing your `case` expression:

```
func (p *Program) Load(ps []datastore.Property) error {
    if err := datastore.LoadStruct(p, ps); err != nil {
        switch err.(type) {
        case *datastore.ErrFieldMismatch:  // use pointer type here
            return nil
        default:
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)